# Creating a hotspot in Lubuntu

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, hot-spot

I am trying to make a hotspot in Lubuntu. The problem is that I can't seem to connect to it. after creating the hotspot how do I activate it? Do I click on "Connect to Hidden Wireless Network" ? I followed this guide, http://freshtutorial.com/create-your-own-wifi-hotspot-in-ubuntu-11-10/ with no success.

Comment: Are you trying to access the hotspot from the same computer/wireless card ?

Answer (score 1):

Open the main menu, then *Preferences*->*Network Connections*.

Select the Network that you want to share, in this case the wifi network that you created. Then click the **Edit...** button.

[image: Edit wifi network]

Choose *Shared to other computers* on the **IPv4** tab

[image: Share_IPv4]

and *Ignore* on the **IPv6** tab.

[image: Ignore_IPv6]

Click **Save...** button on the *Editing*  dialog, and then the **Close** button on the *Network Connections* dialog.

Comment: This answer is unclear. Could you please elaborate upon what you are trying to say, possibly adding screenshots?

Comment: @bloo, I'd like to use a cable connection and share the Internet with my tablet. So should I do the process you said on the cable connection or should I create a new one wireless and do the solution to it?

Comment: Now, how others would connect to my network?

Answer (score 1):

The answer mentioned by @bloo is good but I needed to add the following details on my setup to work.

1. Make sure you specify the "device" you want to use. Mine was Wi-Fi card labeled "wlp4s0"
2. I had to set "Cloned Mac Address" to "preserve.

Check the picture for more details
[image]

In addition, on Lubuntu to make the hotspot work. I had to install the following through the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install hostapd
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

Then I could start the hotspot clicking on "Creating New WIFI Network" and then selecting the specific network profile you just created. The hotspot should start.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing internet is a simple task
Let us assume that wlan0 is the source and eth0 is the host which in turn connected to a LAN (which does not have internet connection). 
Here we need to share the internet connection from wlan0 to eth0.

1. open network manager and click edit on eth0.
2. Now browse the tab IP4 settings and change the method to "Share to other computers".
3. The same way browse to IP6 settings and change the method to "ignore".
4. Restart the network services in both the computer and the router.

Now your internet is shared.....