# How can I create a hotspot in Lubuntu 20?

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, hot-spot

I want to create local network, which would allow other computers to connect.

I have not found way to do this.

Not a duplicate of [Creating a hotspot in Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129579/creating-a-hotspot-in-lubuntu) as their answers is not usable in Lubuntu 20.

Comment: Lubuntu 20?   Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format for all desktop & server releases, and *yy* for all *snap* based releases. Lubuntu being a desktop and being *deb* based is *yy.mm* so please clarify as there is no Lubuntu 20.

Comment: My specific version is 20.04.1 LTS but I hope for answer that will stay accurate across all subversions of Lubuntu 20

Comment: Lubuntu won't ever produce a *snap* based release, we are *deb* based so will always be *yy.mm* format, and almost any setting in Lubuntu 20.04 LTS (LXQt 14.1 I think I recall) applies in LXQt 15.0 found in *groovy*, however a release with the 20 implies it's *snap* based with Ubuntu's release formatting, which won't apply to a desktop or Lubuntu.